# Как найти максимальный элемент среди списков под соответствующим номером?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вводится натуральное число x >= 2, список списков, который состоит из x элементов по x чисел в элементе. Необходимо построить список, состоящий из x элементов, каждый из которых является максимальным среди элементов списков с соответствующим номером. Сравнивается сначала числа 2, 7, 0. 7 добавляется в список и т.д. . Пример: дан список [[2,4,12], [7,-1,11], [0,5,2]
Результат: [7,5,12]

```
n = int(input('Введите кол-во списков в списке: '))                                       
my_list = []
result = []
if n >= 2:
    for _ in range(n):
        elem = [int(i) for i in input('Введите числа во вложенном списке: ').split()]   
        my_list.append(elem)
    print('Исходный список: ', my_list)


else:
    print('Перебор элементов закончился')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить можно довольно просто:

```
a = [[2, 4, 12], [7, -1, 11], [0, 5, 2]]

b = [max(x) for x in zip(*a)]

print(b) # [7, 5, 12]
```

Comment: Как вариант `b = list(map(max, zip(*a)))` это в общем тоже самое, но в "функциональном стиле" )

Comment: @CrazyElf да, можно и так)